# How to validate if name is duplicate in the uploaded file?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, maatwebsite-excel

How to display a validation message if name field is duplicate in the uploaded file?

```
<?php

namespace App\Imports;
use App\Models\Customer;
use Illuminate\Support\Collection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\ToCollection;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithHeadingRow;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Concerns\WithValidation;

class CustomerImport implements ToCollection, WithHeadingRow, WithValidation
{
    public $timestamps = false;
   

    public function collection(Collection $rows)
    {
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            
            Customer::create([
                'name'     => $row['name'],
                'address'  => $row['address'],
            ]);
             
        }
    }

    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            'name'      => [
                'required',
                'max:50',
                'unique:customers,name',
            ],
            'address'      => [
                'required',
                'max:50',
                'unique:customers,address',
            ]
        
        ];
    }
}
```

My sample uploaded csv file is as follows: The name 'AAA' is duplicate. So I need to get validation error message displayed for duplicate entry in the file.

Name,Address

AAA,testaddress

AAA,testaddress1

BBB,address2

Right now I am getting Illuminate\Database\QueryException
SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'AAA' error.

My Controller Code is as follows:

```
public function uploadFile(Request $request)
{
        $request->validate(
            ['file' => ['required', 'file', 'mimes:txt,csv']],
            ['file.required' => 'Please upload the file']
        );
        try {
            Excel::import(new CustomerImport(), $request->file('file'));
        } catch (\Maatwebsite\Excel\Validators\ValidationException $e) {
            $failures = $e->failures();
            return redirect()
                ->route('customers.upload')
                ->withErrors($failures);
        }
        return redirect()
            ->route('customers.index')
            ->with('success', __('customers.message_uploaded'));
    }
```

Comment: Are you doing this? https://docs.laravel-excel.com/3.1/imports/validation.html#gathering-all-failures-at-the-end, i.e. adding a `try { ... } catch (\Maatwebsite\Excel\Validators\ValidationException $e) { ... }` around this logic?

Comment: @Tim Lewis Yes, I have added that in my controller as above (Please check uploadFile())

Comment: Interesting; the only real difference I can see with your code vs the example code is the useage of `$row[0]` and `$row['name']`, and the way the rules reference `0 => ...` vs `'name' => ...` in `public function rules()`. It looks like a `ValidationException` is never being triggered, but you'll have to dig into why.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by creating a custom validation rule. An example implementation using `Maatwebsite` library can be:

##### File: `app\Rules\CsvUnique.php`

```php
namespace App\Rules;

use App\Imports\CustomerImport;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Rule;
use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;

class CsvUnique implements Rule
{

    public function __construct($column)
    {
        $this->column = $column;
    }

    public function passes($attribute, $value)
    {
        $data = Excel::toArray(new CustomerImport(), $value);

        $names = array_map(function($i) {
            return $i[0];
        }, array_slice($data[0],1));

        return count($names) === count(array_unique($names));
    }

    public function message()
    {
        return 'The :attribute has already been taken.';
    }
}
```

Then you can use it inside your validation logic like this:

```php
$request->validate(
    ['file' => ['required', 'file', 'mimes:txt,csv', new CsvUnique('name')]],
    ['file.required' => 'Please upload the file']
);
```

**Note** that we pass the column name, in this canse `name` to the custom rule.

Comment: got undefined offset 0 error . so modified as follows: $names = array_map(function($i) {
            return $i['name'];
        }, array_slice($data[0],1)); But still getting same error

Comment: @Hello I tested this on my local machine on a CSV file with your structure and it worked fine. It is maybe because of `$data[0]`. Try to dd the `$data` before map to see if it has item 0.